# Laravel - Query just one row in a pivot table and return all data within the relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

Currently, a `criteria` BelongsToMany `alerts` and viceversa. They are related through a pivot table: `criteria_id` and `alert_id`.

I am getting all `Criteria` with the associated `Alerts` that belongs to the authenticated user, as such:

```
public function getMatches()
    {
        $matches = Criteria::whereUserId( Auth::id() )
        ->has('alerts')
        ->get();

    }
```

This returns all associated results, whereas now, if a user picks a certain result, I want to be able to show just that. This is what I have so far:

**Controller**

```
public function getMatchDetails($alert_id, $criteria_id)
{

    $matches = Alert::find($alert_id)
    ->has('criterias')
    ->where('criteria_id', $criteria_id)
    ->get();

}
```

Which is bringing over the correct variables, however, I am getting a MYSQL error:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'criteria_id' in 'where clause'

```
select * from `alerts` where `alerts`.`deleted_at` is null and 
(select count(*) from `criterias` inner join `alert_criteria` on `criterias`.`id` =
`alert_criteria`.`criteria_id` where `alert_criteria`.`alert_id` = `alerts`.`id`)
>= 1 and `criteria_id` = 7)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: im confused as to what you mean by "if a user picks a certain result". The first query is not getting the associated relationship, it is just checking for existance of the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
public function getMatchDetails($alert_id, $criteria_id)
{

    $match = Alert::whereHas('criterias', function ($q) use ($criteria_id) {
        $q->where('criteria_id', $criteria_id);
    })->find($alert_id);

}
```

Which will find the alert by id and also check that it has a relationship to criterias meeting those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well the question, but I'm going to try to answer

If you want to pass more than just a variable from the view to the controller, you can do something like this:
View

```
@foreach($matches as $match)
    @foreach($match->alerts as $alert)
        <td>{{$alert->pivot->criteria_id}}</td>
        <td><a href="/users/alert/matches/{{{$alert->id}}}/{{{$var_2}}}">{{$alert->id}}</a></td> 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function getMatchDetails($id, $var_2 = 0)
{
        $myCriteriaIds = Criteria::whereUserId( Auth::id() )
        ->lists('id');

        $match = Alert::find($id)->criterias()
                        ->wherePivot('criteria_id', 'IN', $myCriteriaIds)
                        ->get();
}
```

Route

```
Route::post('/users/alert/matches/{id}/{var_2}', array(
    'as' => 'users-alert-matches',
    'uses' => 'XXXController@getMatchDetails'
));
```

Comment: Many thanks for this @jibe_84, it has cleared a lot up. I am still struggling on the final query (please see updated question).

Comment: ok great! so try to change your where clause in your controller by "->where('criteria.id', $criteria_id)" // criteria_id to criteria.id